# How to I compile uget from source?

Tags: compiling, install-from-source, uget

I've downloaded uget from its source fourge link. It is a tar.gz file. I have read that i could install a file of this type by extracting its contents and following these steps.

```
./configure
make
install
```

But, when I give ./configure

> checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
>
> checking whether build environment is sane - configure error

Am i following the steps? What am I missing? I know the easiest way is to do

> sudo apt-get install uget

But i want to know the reason for its failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But i want to know the reason for its failure.

The reason is right there: you do not have a "sane" (i.e. proper) build environment.

Did you install the essential tools with `sudo apt-get install build-essential`? If not, do that first.

Then, if you are trying to compile a package that is available in the repositories, do yourself a favor and run the below to get all its dependencies without having to figure each one out individually:

`sudo apt-get build-dep uget -y`

The correct steps to follow after that are:

```
cd uget-source-directory
./configure
make
make install
```

---

If `apt-get build-dep` is not possible for some package, look at the `README` or `INSTALL` files in its source directory to find out its dependencies. Otherwise, you'll have to figure the dependencies out one at a time and install them like this:

`configure: error: The intltool scripts were not found. Please install intltool.`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @izx I didn't installed this sudo apt-get install build-essential